# Can I customize authentication with nginx?

Tags: nginx, authentication

I have a private network with many servers and web based services running on it.  There is no application level authentication.  I would like to expose many of the servers to the internet, but I want to proxy it behind nginx with nginx providing authentication.  HttpAuthBasicModule is not sufficient, I would like to use scrypt for password digests, rate limit logins, and log the login attempts.

I am formidable with Python, but I am lost with C.  Any advise?

Comment: Advice: Instead of getting stuck on the idea of using a certain tool, decide what you actually need to do, then find (or create, if necessary) the right tool to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Good observation, I'll try implementing it with twisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the http_auth_request module is suitable for your task. [Repo](http://mdounin.ru/hg/ngx_http_auth_request_module/). [Docs](http://mdounin.ru/hg/ngx_http_auth_request_module/file/a29d74804ff1/README).

For rate limiting login attempts you can easily utilize [nginx limit req module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html). For custom log: [nginx log module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html). All these modules would be suitable for you in combination with the [location](http://nginx.org/r/location) directive.